# jQuery, how to remove an anonymous function

Tags: ajax, jquery

I use `AJAX` to load some data into main page. For instance, I insert the code below:

```
<div id="content_apps">
<script>
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){    
    alert('needs to be deleted!');
});
</script>

<div id="navigation-block">
<!-- SOME CODE -->
</div>
</div>
```

After using it, I use `$("#content_apps").remove();` function to remove this content. When I insert it again the `alert('needs to be deleted!');` is invoked twice. How to remove this anonymous function?

Comment: Put the JS code into the main page, not the file you load with AJAX.

Comment: I can't. It must be invoked just after inserting some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to unbind the event handler.

```
$(document).unbind('ajaxComplete');
```

Comment: It works, but it completely unbinds all anonymous functions inside `ajaxComplete`. But anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a namespace and unbind on that specific namespace:

http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events